# URL rewrite, preserve natural paths

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm writing a default .htaccess for a system that runs multiple JS app packages. I want to have URL rewrites that forward to run of these apps from the root (i.e. if the system is included at *www/*, *www/appname/* should forward to *server.index.php?app=appname*).

Here's roughly what I have now (I'll skip the other stuff in my .htaccess).

```
RewriteRule ^use/?([^/]*)/?([^/]*)/?([^/]*)/? \server/index.php?app=$1&servable=$2&action=$3
RewriteRule ^web/?([^/]*)/? \server/index.php?servable=clients&action=web&app=$1
```

As you can see, I'm currently using two endpoints: *use* forwards to any action in the backend, while *web* forwards to the action that actually serves the application itself as an HTML document. **I basically want to skip the *web/* prefix in the URL in the latter case, but without hindering access to natural directories that already exist in the system's directory.**

Here's [full source](https://bitbucket.org/Eiskis/proot/src/3f46120eae37/.htaccess). (As you can see there are probably other issues with my .htaccess as well, so if you have any pointers I'm happy to fix them.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I basically want to skip the web/ prefix in the URL in the latter case, but without hindering access to natural directories that already exist in the system's directory.

You can check that using the condition flags `-f` and `-d`. So if you include these conditions right above the **/web** rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

meaning the requested URI doesn't map to an existing file or directory, then:

```
RewriteRule ^/?([^/]*)/? \server/index.php?servable=clients&action=web&app=$1
```

except without the `/web` part.